# Como fazer upload de arquivos para meu servidor usando Java servlets

Tags: java, web-service, upload, servlet

Como fazer upload de arquivos para meu servidor usando Java servlets, e após subir o arquivo retornar a url em que o arquivo se encontra, onde o nome é originado da data e hora em que o arquivo foi enviado para que não aja repetições de nomes, alguém teria ideia de como implementar?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Ainda não @Marconi, eu gostaria de saber qual o melhor caminho para fazer isso.

Comment: Aqui tem um tutorial, você pode segui-lo para ter uma ideia de como implementar. E depois fazer suas próprias modificações. [Upload de Arquivos com Servlet 3](http://www.mballem.com/post/upload-de-arquivos-com-servlet-3/)